# How to use OR in query with priority?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select

In a simple query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id='x' OR id='y'
```

How to give a priority to get only one of the `WHERE` clauses?

I mean getting rows with `id='x'`. Only if there is no row, get row with `id='y'`.

In other words, do not use `id='y'` if there is a row for `id='x'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table
WHERE  id IN ('x', 'y')
AND    (id='x' OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM table WHERE id='x'))
```

should do the trick (caveat: I'm an MSSQL guy and haven't tried that in mySQL, but I suspect that syntax is accepted just fine there too) though the efficiency will depend on how many rows matching the first filtering clause there are (for every row matching `id='x' OR id='y'` he subquery in the `EXISTS` part will probably be run unless the query planner is bright enough to see that it depends on nothing in the outer query so can be run once and the result reused - if you are only expecting at most two (which with a column name like `id` I suspect is the case) this should not be an issue)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a MySQL guy either but believe that this does the trick.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM table
WHERE id='x' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND id='y'
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether this is documented/guaranteed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to make it easier for the planner with a `UNION ALL` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id=x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE id=y
ORDER BY id='x'
LIMIT 1;
```

Works in PostgreSQL anyway.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT
    x::int % 7 AS a,
    5 AS b
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6::int)
    AS gs(x);

CREATE INDEX ON foo (a);
ANALYZE foo;


explain analyze SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a=5 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM foo WHERE b = 5 LIMIT 1;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..45287.67 rows=1143767 width=8) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16925.00 rows=143767 width=8) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (a = 5)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 4
         ->  Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..16925.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (never executed)
               Filter: (b = 5)
 Planning time: 0.203 ms
 Execution time: 0.061 ms
(9 rows)
```

`(never executed)` means your job is done.